# Validation for non-negative integers and decimal values

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My fields are:
`tax rate` and `tax amount` in which I want to validate positive values.

I wrote this validation:

```
:format => { :with => /\A[+]?\d+\Z/}
```

But it is not taking numbers with a decimal point like `4.67`.
And it's throwing me an error.
What type of validation will work on integers and floating point values?
for example: `2`, `57`, `54.56` should pass but `-2.56`, `-87` should fail.

Answer (score 148):

Doesn't this work?

```
validates :your_field, :numericality => { :greater_than_or_equal_to => 0 }
```

(guess for taxes following rule will be more correct:)

```
validates :your_field, :numericality => { :greater_than_or_equal_to => 0, :less_than_or_equal_to => 100 }
```

Comment: is the field a string or a float? If it's not a string, you shouldn't be doing regexp on it. Something like this example would be better. You'd need a validation that just checks if it's < 0

Comment: be wary of numericality as a validator.  There's a gotcha.  As per rails guides 'By default, numericality doesn't allow nil values. You can use allow_nil: true option to permit it.'

Answer (score 8):

You could use:

```
validates :tax_rate, inclusion: { in: 0..5 }
```

It allows values like: **0, 2, 1.2, 3.2**

Hope it helps!

Comment: I used that very same syntax in some validation I was testing earlier but decided to not use it. If a user enters a value outside of that range, they receive an error which reads something like, "value is not included." I opted for a solution like `:greater_than_or_equal_to` because the user is presented with a more meaningful error.

Answer (score 5):

you could use `validates_numericality_of :amount, :greater_than => 0.0`

Comment: This is using the older style `validates_x_of` style that's been supplanted by the more generalized `validates` approach.