# Datatype model validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Ruby on Rails, I can't seem to find a validation model method to check for data-type.

I was hoping for something like

```
validates :name, datatype: :integer
```

but there is nothing on http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html

If such a test not required? Is it because the database engine (mysql or whatever) itself would reject information with a wrong data-type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you are new to Rails there are already predefined validations in rails Ref [Active Record Validations](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#numericality) in Rails

```
validates :name, numericality: true
```

or

```
validates :name, numericality: { only_integer: true }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like

```
validates :your_field, :numericality => { :greater_than_or_equal_to => 0 }
```

please check the link

[Validation for non-negative integers and decimal values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11806498/validation-for-positive-integer-and-decimal-values)

Answer (score 1):

There is a validation for this in Rails

```
validates_numericality_of :value, :only_integer: true
```